# How to find the inverse of a function involving e with a coefficient?

Tags: exponential-function, inverse

I was wondering how I would find the inverse of the following function, since the e has a co-efficient:

$\frac{e^x}{1+2e^x}=y$

I got as far as $\ln y+\ln(2e^x) = \ln e^x$, which would be changed into:

$\ln y + \ln(2e^x) = x\ln e$ (or just $x$)

But where do I go from here?

Comment: Divide the numerator and denominator by $e^x$ to get $1/(e^{-x}+2)=y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{e^x}{1+2e^x}=\frac1{e^{-x}+2}$, so $e^{-x}=\frac1y-2$.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for setting me on the right track. Using this I found the inverse function to be -ln(1/x -2) = y. Would that be correct?

Comment: That is correct; you can further include the "$-$" into $\ln$ as "$^{-1}$".